# Apply the select privilege to all users in mysql

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have 30 plus MySQL users their permissions vary from one another.

I want to `GRANT SELECT` privilege to all of the 30 users. Is there any one command that I can use that can `grant select` to all 30 users in one shot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| eroom            | localhost |
| musr             | localhost |
| musr             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select concat('GRANT SELECT ON *.* to "',user,'"@"',host,'";') into outfile '/tmp/select_script.sql' FROM mysql.user;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> source /tmp/select_script.sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Would something like 'GRANT SELECT ON *.My_Database...." be better - i.e. specify the database, rather than granting SELECT on everything?

Comment: Always. Only providing the minimal and most granular is erring on the side of caution and security best practice.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to GRANT SELECT privilege to all of the 30 users. Is there any one command that I can use that can grant select to all 30 users in one shot!

Yes.

```
grant select on *.* to user_group ;
```

... where every user who should have this access is a member of this group.

Working with lots of individual users opens up the risk of getting into *exactly* the situation you're currently in - inconsistency.  Use groups/roles to make your security landscape consistent, safer and easier to manage.